# Is it possible to filter by account type and date?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have two datasets, the products and services tables.

Basically, the business logic is: I acquire products (I can have multiple products but only 2 active the rest have to be in "inactive status") and I can subscribe services. The service is like an insurance for the product that I acquire, and I can have more than one service per account.

Note: active products have a start date and no end date. Inactive products have a start date and an end date.

I don't know if what I need is possible to develop in Power Bi, but what I want is two filters, one is the date and the other is the account type.

I tried to develop an example, in Power Bi. I have the products table, services table and I created a new table (manually) that gives me the account type.

The example has 3 accounts (imagine we are in January 2023) :

- 1 account with 2 inactive products and 2 inactive services;
- 1 account with 1 active product and 1 active service;
- 1 account with 1 inactive product without services.

If I filter by July 2022 and select "All" for the Account Type filter, what I pretend to watch is a donut chart with 1 service A and 2 service B.

If I filter by "Dual" (and the filter date remains unchanged) I want to watch 1 service A and 1 service B.

To conclude, what I need to know is if it is possible to make this account type table (or another approach that allows me to have the account type) and then if it is possible to have this filter and that it can relate to the metric that I created of "# active services" (in the example that I develop it is not related well because despite the connection between tables there is no date factor which causes the results to be incorrect).

**Product Table (Code):**

```
let
Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUTIw1AciIwMjIyDH2FDf0AjGMQXigKL8lNLkEgVHLCoNzCGcWB1CJhmbIRnlBFVqhkUpyCgjqLwxTB6ITLC5BaEApM0Yw1gDfUMDGMfCFK8LEEpjYwE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [acct_id = _t, acct_start_date = _t, acct_end_date = _t, product_id = _t, product_name = _t, product_start_date = _t, product_end_date = _t]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"acct_id", Int64.Type}, {"acct_start_date", type date}, {"acct_end_date", type date}, {"product_id", Int64.Type}, {"product_name", type text}, {"product_start_date", type date}, {"product_end_date", type date}})
in
#"Changed Type"
```

[product_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFntJ.png)

**Service Table (Code):**

```
let
Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUTIw1AciIwMjIyDH2FDf0AjGMTEFEsGpRWWZyakKjniUxuoQMsrCDMkoJ6hSMxxGGUHljWHyQGRpiWaAoSmygthYAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [acct_id = _t, acct_start_date = _t, acct_end_date = _t, service_id = _t, service_name = _t, service_start_date = _t, service_end_date = _t]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"acct_id", Int64.Type}, {"acct_start_date", type date}, {"acct_end_date", type date}, {"service_id", Int64.Type}, {"service_name", type text}, {"service_start_date", type date}, {"service_end_date", type date}})
in
#"Changed Type"
```

[service_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtQaD.png)

**Account Table (Code):**

```
let
Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMlTSUTIw1AciIwMjIyDH2FDf0AjG8c3Py1fQVQgoyk8pTS5RcMSi2MAUwonVIWSYS2liDlSBGbIB5sQagOYaJ6hiCyyKQYYZQeWNYfK4PYRQAtJojOFKA31DAwKuwKY4NhYA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [acct_id = _t, acct_start_date = _t, acct_end_date = _t, account_type = _t, start_date = _t, end_date = _t]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"acct_id", Int64.Type}, {"acct_start_date", type date}, {"acct_end_date", type date}, {"account_type", type text}, {"start_date", type date}, {"end_date", type date}})
in
#"Changed Type"
```

[account_type_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqrw6.png)

**Dim_Date:**

[dim_date_layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urhqN.png)

**Measure:**

```
# active_services = 
VAR Data = 
    MAX(Dim_Date[Date])
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(fact_services_table[service_id]),
    ALL(dim_Date[Date]),
    fact_services_table[service_start_date] <> BLANK(),
    fact_services_table[service_start_date] <= Data,
        OR(
            fact_services_table[service_end_date] > Data,
            fact_services_table[service_end_date] = BLANK()
        )
)
```

**Model:**

[relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuJzt.png)

**Final Output:**

[account_type_all_filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ty9Qn.png)

[account_type_dual_filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSH5Z.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Should this be an individual, unpaid consulting service? This is hardly interesting for other users.